# How to install multiple CouchBase instance in a single linux server?

Tags: linux, nosql, couchbase

I'm trying to install multiple Couchabse instance in a single linux sever. I know this is not good for performance, but it is just for training purpose. I just need to demonstrate the node removal, failover and all.

Here's how I installed couchbase.

`sudo rpm --install couchbase-server-community-5.1.1-centos7.x86_64.rpm`

But I could't customize anything. It just got installed in a flash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the easiest way is to run it on docker/docker compose, here are some tutorials on how to do it:

https://blog.couchbase.com/use-xdcr-replicate-nosql-data-couchbase-docker-containers/
https://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-xdcr-docker-swarm-machine-compose/

Comment: I read in documentation that we can directly install multiple instances as non root. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes you can. But docker compose is a single file is much more simple if the people in your training also need to install it.